# How to create a non-superuser in HDFS with kerberos enabled

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I used the cloudera-quickstart-vm to build up a hadoop cluster and integerted it with kerberos (no AD or LDAP, **ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping**).Then I tried to create some users, but found they were all in **superuser** group. So how can I create a user in **non-superuser** group?

[image: operation]

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is a virtual file-system which means you can not directly create a user like you do in Linux. So, in HDFS you have to create a user directory as an HDFS user.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/<user_name>
```

Now, it will be added to HDFS group by default which is a super-user group. So, you need to edit the owner permissions. For that, you can simply run chown command :

```
hdfs dfs -chown -R [user]:[group] /user/<user_name>
```

That's all.

Comment: I created a HDFS directory /tmp/etl owned by hdfs:etl (permission 770). Then I made the HDFS direcotry /user/user1 owned by user1:etl, and I also used the host command usermod to make user1 in etl group. But the user1 still had no permission to create any directory in /tmp/etl, why?

Comment: @rugalcrimson Sorry for the late reply. Now, let me tell you where did you go wrong, but first I tell you how I followed what u said:
1. Created a unix user "user1" 
2. Create etl group in unix and added user1 to etl group
3.  created /tmp/etl directory and set permissions and owners as u said
4. created /user/user1 as u said and changed the group
Now, the real problem begins:
5. logged in as a user1 user, tried hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/etl/abc but generated an error. WHY?
Bcz hdfs is a superuser, you cannot perform any action in hdfs until and unless u r hdfs user just like it is with root